# jQuery flip elements overlapping subsequent elements

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, ejs

I'm using the [jQuery flip plugin](https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/#Options) to flip images in an ejs file in node.

The flip animation works, but any element below the flip element overlaps with the flip element.

Simple code that illustrates my issue:

```
<head>
     <title>James Riley</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nnattawat/flip/master/dist/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div>Something before the flip</div>
        <div id="flipImage">
            <div class="front">front content</div>
            <div class="back">back content</div>
        </div>
    <div>Something after the flip</div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/about.js"></script>
</body>
```

And then in about.js:

```
$("#flipImage").flip();
```

This causes "Something after the flip" to overlap with front/back content. If the content is text it literally writes over the subsequent text.

Sorry if this is obvious. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source they are absolute positioning the front and back elements.  It may be a bit hacky but you could set the height when your calling the flip function:

```
var height =  $("#flipImage").outerHeight();
$("#flipImage").flip().height(height);
```

and add this style to the container:

```
display:flex;
justify-content: flex-start
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like this is a known issue with the plugin:

> "When I flip it to the back, which is the long sidebar, it doesn't
>   expand the container to fill the sidebar. Instead it just overlaps the
>   content..."

You can follow the status on the [github issue page.](https://github.com/nnattawat/flip/issues/70)

Maybe you'd be interested in CSS flip tricks instead? 
Here is a cool example from [David Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php)

```css
/* simple */

.flip-container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -moz-perspective: 1000;
  -ms-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;
  -ms-transform: perspective(1000px);
  -moz-transform: perspective(1000px);
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
/*
   .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper, #flip-toggle.flip .flipper {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    filter: FlipH;
       -ms-filter: "FlipH";
   }
   */

/* START: Accommodating for IE */

.flip-container:hover .back,
.flip-container.hover .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.flip-container:hover .front,
.flip-container.hover .front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
/* END: Accommodating for IE */

.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
  width: 320px;
  height: 427px;
}
.flipper {
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transition: 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: 0.6s;
  -moz-transform: perspective(1000px);
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}
.front,
.back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transition: 0.6s;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -o-transition: 0.6s;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -ms-transition: 0.6s;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  background: lightgreen;
  z-index: 2;
}
.back {
  background: lightblue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.front .name {
  font-size: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.9);
  color: #f8f8f8;
  font-family: Courier;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 60px;
  left: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.05em #333;
  display: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-20deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-20deg);
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
}
.back-logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 90px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 117px;
  background: url(logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.back-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #00304a;
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.05em #acd7e5;
  font-family: Courier;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.back p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
/* vertical */

.vertical.flip-container {
  position: relative;
}
.vertical .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.vertical.flip-container .flipper {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 213.5px;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 213.5px;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 213.5px;
  transform-origin: 100% 213.5px;
}
/*
   .vertical.flip-container:hover .flipper {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    transform: rotateX(-180deg);
   }
   */

/* START: Accommodating for IE */

.vertical.flip-container:hover .back,
.vertical.flip-container.hover .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
.vertical.flip-container:hover .front,
.vertical.flip-container.hover .front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
/* END: Accommodating for IE */
```

```html
<p>Mouse over the image below to see it flip!</p>

<h2>Styled Card (Horizontal Flip)</h2>
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front" style="background: url(https://davidwalsh.name/demo/dwflip.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;">
      <span class="name">David Walsh</span>
    </div>
    <div class="back" style="background:#f8f8f8;">
      <div class="back-logo"></div>
      <div class="back-title">@davidwalshblog</div>
      <p>Mozilla Web Developer, MooTools & jQuery Consultant, MooTools Core Developer, Javascript Fanatic, CSS Tinkerer, PHP Hacker, and web lover.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />

<h2>Styled Card (Vertical Flip)</h2>
<div class="flip-container vertical" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front" style="background: url(https://davidwalsh.name/demo/dwflip.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;">
      <span class="name">David Walsh</span>
    </div>
    <div class="back" style="background:#f8f8f8;">
      <div class="back-logo"></div>
      <div class="back-title">@davidwalshblog</div>
      <p>Mozilla Web Developer, MooTools & jQuery Consultant, MooTools Core Developer, Javascript Fanatic, CSS Tinkerer, PHP Hacker, and web lover.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />


<h2>Toggle Flip (Horizontal)</h2>
<div class="flip-container" id="flip-toggle">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front" style="background: url(https://davidwalsh.name/demo/dwflip.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;">
      <span class="name">David Walsh</span>
    </div>
    <div class="back" style="background:#f8f8f8;">
      <div class="back-logo"></div>
      <div class="back-title">@davidwalshblog</div>
      <p>Mozilla Web Developer, MooTools & jQuery Consultant, MooTools Core Developer, Javascript Fanatic, CSS Tinkerer, PHP Hacker, and web lover.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="document.querySelector('#flip-toggle').classList.toggle('hover');" class="sexyButton">Toggle Flip</button>
<br />
<br />

<h2>Just The Basics (Horizontal Flip)</h2>
<!-- card -->
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front">
      front
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      back
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
```